# Linq get all objects that implement interface

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

Is it possible to get something like this:

```
return Session.Query<A>().Where(x => x is B).ToList();
```

where B derives from A working for an interface (i.e. get all objects that implement certain interface)? Thanks.

Comment: It has an `OfType<B>()` call, but I'm not sure if it's compatible with `Session.Query`; probably is but I'm not confident enough to post it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly convert this statement to SQL. First you will have to evaluate the query or use `AsEnumerable()`.

```
return Session.Query<A>().AsEnumerable().Where(x => x is B).ToList();
```

Or:

```
return Session.Query<A>().AsEnumerable().OfType<B>().ToList();
```

The part after the `AsEnumerable` will be executed in memory.

Comment: Thanks. This basically means that I have to get all objects first from the database, which would be bad in my situation.

Comment: Yes, SQL server has no information about interfaces your objects implements. I would suggest to create some discriminator column upon which you can filter "types" of your objects. I would also recommend not to mix your business layer interfaces with entity mapping -> it would be better create one domain layer above and put those interfaces there.